# Создать массив из строки и вернуть новый массив

Tags: javascript, массивы

Задача: задается строка, необходимо вернуть массив состоящий из пар символов, если у последней пары не хватает символа добавить вместо него `"_"`
Пример: `"abcde"` => `[ab, cd, e_]`

```
function solution(str){
  var arrLetters=[];
  var result = [];

  arrLetters = str.split("");
  if (arrLetters.length % 2 != 0) arrLetters.push("_"); 

  for (let s=0;s<arrLetters.length;s++) {result.splice( result.length,0,arrLetters[s]+arrLetters[s+1])}; 
  for (let s=0;s<arrLetters.length;s++) {result.splice(s+1,s)};
  return (result);//(1) смотреть ниже
}
console.log(solution("abcde"), "ab", "cd", "e_");
```

Вринципе код рабочий, но я бы хотел улучшить его. Если можно с подробным описанием ваших решений.
Пытался найти метод которым можно записать в массив сразу 2 символа без лишних манипуляций строка (1)

Answer (score 5):

```js
function solution(str) {
  return str.split('')
    .map((c, i, ar) => c + (ar[i + 1] ? ar[i + 1] : '_')) // объединяем каждый символ со следующим
    .filter((c, i) => 1 - i % 2); // убираем четные пары
}
console.log(solution("abcde"), "ab", "cd", "e_");
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
const solution = (str) => {
  return str.match(/..?/g).map(x => {return x.length % 2 === 0 ? x : x + '_'});
}
console.log(solution('abcde'), 'ab', 'cd', 'e_');
```